# Identifying location in list of runtimeWarning in python

Tags: python

I have a script that loops through a list and at certain points generates a runtimeWarning. I want to flag these locations, but not kill the loop. I just want to identify the locations of the warnings.

Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
#define NumPy arrays
x = np.array([4, 5, 5, 7, 0,10])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6, 7, 0,2])

#divide the values in x by the values in y
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    tmp_x = x[i]
    tmp_y = y[i]
    print(np.divide(tmp_x, tmp_y))
```

Setting warnings to errors breaks the loop, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Have you tried using try/except? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Also, you should use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two lists. (Using `for i in range():` is nearly always a code smell in python.)

Comment: "I want to flag these locations" - what exactly does this mean? How is this different from what happens normally?

Comment: @Karl I think they want the value of `i` when the error occurs. (It doesn't necessarily correspond with the output due to buffering.)

Comment: Is it significant that you're using NumPy for this instead of lists? I mean, NumPy arrays support vectorized operations, so instead of looping and dividing each element manually, you could just do `x / y`. That said, I don't know how to get the indexes where warnings occurred, but in this case it's as simple as checking `isnan()`, i.e. `np.argwhere(np.isnan(result))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rule that would produce an error given a warning and try-catch it:

```py
import warnings

import numpy as np


warnings.filterwarnings("error")

x = np.array([4, 5, 5, 7, 0, 10])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 2])

for index, (x_element, y_element) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    try:
        result = np.divide(x_element, y_element)
        print(result)
    except RuntimeWarning as warning:
        print(f"RuntimeWarning at [{index}] ({warning})")
```

Output:

```
2.0
1.25
0.8333333333333334
1.0
RuntimeWarning at [4] (invalid value encountered in divide)
5.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `warning` module.
[warnings module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

```
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("error")

x = np.array([4, 5, 5, 7, 0, 10])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 2])

for i, (_x, _y) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    
    try:
        result = np.divide(_x, _y)
        print(result)
    except RuntimeWarning as warning:
        print(f"Runtime warning at index {i} : {warning}")
```

Add `try` block and `catch` the `RuntimeWarning`  using `except`.

When a warning occurs, it will print the location (index) of the warning along with the warning message.

This allows you to identify the locations of the warnings without stopping the loop.

hope this helps

Comment: @MatBailie - Yes, you are right. Thanks for correcting me. I  have used the same variables and replaced the solution with the possible one.

Comment: Thanks. So how do you identify the index? The range solution allows me to do that. Also curious as to why the range approach is a mistake? I have some loops that break due to network connections and it allows me to restart where I left off. Not sure how to do that with zip.

Comment: `warnings.RuntimeWarning` doesn't exist. Did you mean the builtin? That's just `RuntimeWarning`. But you can't catch it by default.